# Can I reliably edit the this pointer in the stack?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a sort of virtual address space in c++ which has its own memory allocation functions and can be moved around in ram. Each residing object has a change_offset(long long int offset) method for changing any pointers it has to point to the new memory location the space will be placed in. But an issue exist if the space is moved by a call that originated from an object inside the space. After the move all of the this pointers inside the stack will be invalid as they will point to the old object location. So what I want to do is have the function that moves the space also go back in the stack and update all the this pointers with the new offset so they now point at the correct location. The below method only overrides the this pointer in some cases where it exists right behind the first argument in the stack but this doesn't seem to always be the case.

```
 void do_s(void *this_trace){
    *(long long int *)(&this_trace-8)=555;
    cout<<(long long int)this<<endl;
}
```

So I want to know if there is a way to reliably have access to the location the this pointer is stored in the stack so I can edit it to contain a new value.

Comment: No. _Comment padding_

Comment: When you are programming in C++ you are not programming against the hardware, you are programming against the C++ abstract machine. You might think something like this works because you operate at a low level, but the truth is that the C++ abstraction prohibits and makes this illegal, even in the situations where it might seem to work.

Comment: You are not guaranteed that the `this` pointer is anywhere on the stack.

Comment: Minor point: `long long int` is usually written `long long`. They mean the same thing.

Comment: In just 1 line of code (the `=555`) there are 4 sources of Undefined Behavior. This should tell you just how much you absolutely are not allowed to do *this* (pun intended).

Comment: @DrewDormann Even if it is not in the stack is there a way to have access to it or force it to be placed somewhere that I can access it?

Comment: The only way to do something like this in this manner is if you make or fork a compiler and create your own dialect of C++.

Comment: Using a *cast* is telling the compiler "There is no problem here, just do the thing."  But, as it would turn out, the thing would, in fact, be a problem.

Comment: The stack unwinding code used in exceptions has the knowledge of how the stack is laied out. So look at how that works for your compiler. And then you have to add code that tracks threads because you have to check every threads stack in case they are inside some method of the moved object. And then you have to scan all of the heap in case there is a pointer to the object there too, which is where you need to patch your compiler.

Comment: If you accept to write compiler and processor dependent code you might use `asm` (in [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)...) or [ASMJIT](https://asmjit.com/) or generate your own plugin (on Linux: use [dlopen](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) with [dlsym](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html)....). Read the [GC handbook](https://gchandbook.org/)